# How to invite a bot to a Microsoft Teams Live Event

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I was wondering if its possible to have a bot join a Live Event, since the documentation does not talk about it.

I have already tried the [PlayBack](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/AudioVideoPlaybackBot) Bot , and i wanted to know if its possible to do something like that, but in a Live Event, since the sample its done on a regular call.

Considering this, i would also like to know if its possible to assign it a presenter role, and if so how do you assign it.

The bot im trying to build is a hosted media application , which could access to the video and audio data streams from the call.

*PS: We were able to join a private organization meeting with an external bot, as a presenter. Is this a bug or is this scenario supported? We are hosting the bot in a tenant **x** and the event in a tenant **y***

I have also opened a issue on github but got no [response](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/221)

Comment: Could you please go through the [Communications graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) If that helps?

Comment: Hey, i have already done so, theres nothing really about it

Comment: When you invite a bot to an live event you bot will receive an activity that you can handle in [incomingcallhandler](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/blob/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/RemoteMediaSamples/IncidentBot/Bot/IncomingCallHandler.cs#L32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally do so, Refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/221) issue on GitHub for further information.